# How to call in a specifc csv field value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, row

I am so new to python (a week in) so I hope I ask this question properly.

I have imported a grade sheet in csv format into python 2.7.  The first column is the name of the student and the column titles are the name of the assignments.  So the data looks something like this:

```
Name    Test1   Test2   Test3   
Robin   89  78  100
...
Rick    72      100     98
```

I want to be able to do (or have someone else do) 3 things just by typing in the name of the person and the assignment.
1. Get the score for that person for that assignment
2. Get the average score for that assignment
3. Get that persons average score

But for some reason I get lost at figuring how to get python to recognize the field I am trying to call in.  So far this is what I have (so far the only part that works is calling in file):

```
 data = csv.DictReader(open("C:\file.csv"))
 for row in data:
    print row

 def grade() 
 student= input ("Enter a student name: ")
 assignment= input("Enter a assignment: ")

 for row in data:
    task_grade= data.get(int(row["student"], int(row["assignment"])) # specific grade
    task_total= sum(int(row['assignment']))  #assignment total
    student_total=  #student assignments total-- no clue how to do this

 task_average= task_total/11
 average_score= student_total/9
```

Comment: please fix parenthesis match. Plus there is something wrong with `def grade()`. Third: it's this python 2 or 3?

Comment: OP specifically states he's using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the individual "columns" of your csv this way:

```
import csv

def parse_csv():
    csv_file = open('data.csv', 'r')
    r = csv.reader(csv_file)
    grade_averages = {}
    for row in r:
        if row[0].startswith('Name'):
            continue
        #print "Student: ", row[0]
        grades = []
        for column in row[1:]:
            #print "Grade: ", column
            grades.append(int(column.strip()))
        grade_total = 0
        for i in grades:
            grade_total += i
        grade_averages[row[0]] = grade_total / len(grades)

    #print "grade_averages: ", grade_averages
    return grade_averages

def get_grade(student_name):
    grade_averages = parse_csv()
    return grade_averages[student_name]

print "Rick: ", get_grade('Rick')
print "Robin: ", get_grade('Robin')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not meant for Python because you have keys and values. However...

If you know that your columns are always the same, no need to use keywords, you can use positions:

Here is the easy, inefficient* way to do 1 and 3:

```
students_name = ...
number = ...
for line in open("C:\file.csv")).readlines()
    items = line.split()
    num_assignments = len(items)-1
    name = items[0]
    if name = students_name:
        print("assignment score: {0}".format(items[number]))
        asum = 0
        for k in range(0,num_assignments):
             asum+= items[k+1]
        print("their average: {0}".format(asum / num_assignments)
```

To do 2, you should precompute the averages and return them beucase the averages for each assignment is the same for each user query.

I say easy *innefficnet because you search the text file for each user query each time a name is entered. To do it properly, you should probably build a dictionary of all names and their information. But that solution is more complicated, and you are only a week in! Moreover, its longer and you should give it a try. Look up `dict`.

Comment: What do you mean by "What you are trying to do is not meant for Python"?

Comment: Well since you have a key value system using a database would be far faster for such queries. My point of building a dict, which would hash the keys for O(1) lookup, is essentially re-creating a database. Anything you do here would be essentially modeling the functionality of a database.

Comment: Interestingly what most answers don't realise is he has already worked out that a dictionary is needed - just seems to be a bit confused about how to use it.  I don't have time to write an answer just now (end of lunch break!) but if there isn't a good answer once I'm free I'll try and do one.  A database seems overkill for something of this simplicity.

Comment: Well, "overkill" depends on how much it is used. The overhead of building it is worth if if you are going to use it a million times. If its just a course assignment the prof will test with 3 names, of course its overkill there.

Comment: also I see no `dict()` in OPs post.

Comment: There are more than 3 names. I just gave similar sample of the data not the actual data. I think I will work on creating a dictionary. I just learned about those.

Comment: There can be more than 3 names.. not sure what you mean. By columns the same I meant that there are no non-assignment columns. Then my upper solution would not work. EDIT: Oh, I meant "the system will not be used much" =). In that case I agree with @neil about not using a DB.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* the reason you are not seeing the field the second time around is because the iterator returned by `csv.DictReader()` is a one-time iterator. That is to say, once you've reached the last row of the csv file, it will not reset to the first position.

So, by doing this:

```
  data = csv.DictReader(open("C:\file.csv"))
  for row in data:
  print row
```

You are running it out. Try commenting those lines and see if that helps.